# How to Remember the State in Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In Eclipse 3.x we can easily know whether application is launching first time or it is restoring the state by checking method `restoreState()` in ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class, but this feature is not available in Eclipse 4.x, So can anyone help me how can I know whether the Eclipse state is restore or not in Eclipse 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a value in the 'persisted state' of the application and check that during start up.

The earliest the application object is available is the `@ProcessAdditions` step of the `LifeCyle` class.

```
@ProcessAdditions
void processAdditions(MApplication app)
{
  String value = app.getPersistedState().get("myKey");

  if (value == null)  // Starting with nothing to restore
   {
     app.getPersistedState().put("myKey", "set");

     ...
   }
  else
   {
     ... persisted state exists
   }

}
```